# What is the complexity of NSComparisonResult? [Post interview]

Tags: ios, objective-c

What is the complexity of NSComparisonResult called on an NSArray?

if i call

```
NSArray *sorted = [[set allObjects] sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(Point pt1, Point pt2) {

   float distance1 = [pt1 distanceToPoint:origin];
   float distance2 = [pt2 distanceToPoint:origin];

   if (distance1 < distance2) {
       return NSOrderedAscending;
   }
   else if (distance1 > distance2) {
       return NSOrderedDescending;
   }
   else if (distance1 == distance2) {
       return NSOrderedSame;
   }

   }];
```

What is the complexity of that sort?

Answer (score 0):

Presumably they're using a binary tree under the hood, making this O(nlogn). That is assuming that I remember what I was taught 12 years ago (and haven't used since).

Incidentally, `NSComparisonResult` is the return value of the block, not the name of a function.